compileSdkVersion is not specified during configuration of project 'expo-camera'
When building my expo react-native app I get the build error:

Where:
Script '/DELIBERATELY_HIDDEN/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 377

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.



A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-camera'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

I've tried every answer in every related post but it hasn't helped.
I've looked at my android project level, android app level and expo-camera node_modules level build.gradle file's, but they all specify a compileSdkVersion!
I don't want to change anything in node_modules as it will be wiped every time I have to reinstall them.
It used to build just fine using expo-camera version 14.1.3, react 18.2.0, react native 0.73.6 & expo 50.0.0 and I haven't changed those versions.
Incidentally, I also get the following in my problems tab in VS Code, but similar errors have happened with other modules, before, without causing build errors:
Missing Gradle project configuration folder: .settings

Here are my build.gradle file's:
Project level:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.8.10'

        ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
    }
}


App level:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

def projectRoot = rootDir.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    entryFile = file(["node", "-e", "require('expo/scripts/resolveAppEntry')", projectRoot, "android", "absolute"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
    reactNativeDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile()
    hermesCommand = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/sdks/hermesc/%OS-BIN%/hermesc"
    codegenDir = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native/codegen/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim()).getParentFile().getAbsoluteFile()

    // Use Expo CLI to bundle the app, this ensures the Metro config
    // works correctly with Expo projects.
    cliFile = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@expo/cli', { paths: [require.resolve('expo/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
    bundleCommand = "export:embed"

    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]

    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = (findProperty('android.enableProguardInReleaseBuilds') ?: false).toBoolean()

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    namespace 'co.uk.tycho.provisioner'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'co.uk.tycho.provisioner'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.0.0"

        buildConfigField("boolean", "REACT_NATIVE_UNSTABLE_USE_RUNTIME_SCHEDULER_ALWAYS", (findProperty("reactNative.unstable_useRuntimeSchedulerAlways") ?: true).toString())

        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'provisionerDebugKey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources (findProperty('android.enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        jniLibs {
            useLegacyPackaging (findProperty('expo.useLegacyPackaging')?.toBoolean() ?: false)
        }
    }
    // flavorDimensions 'react-native-camera'
    // productFlavors {
    //     general {
    //         dimension 'react-native-camera'
    //     }
    //     mlkit {
    //         dimension 'react-native-camera'
    //     }
    // }
}

// Apply static values from `gradle.properties` to the `android.packagingOptions`
// Accepts values in comma delimited lists, example:
// android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts=/LICENSE,**/picasa.ini
["pickFirsts", "excludes", "merges", "doNotStrip"].each { prop ->
    // Split option: 'foo,bar' -> ['foo', 'bar']
    def options = (findProperty("android.packagingOptions.$prop") ?: "").split(",");
    // Trim all elements in place.
    for (i in 0..<options.size()) options[i] = options[i].trim();
    // `[] - ""` is essentially `[""].filter(Boolean)` removing all empty strings.
    options -= ""

    if (options.length > 0) {
        println "android.packagingOptions.$prop += $options ($options.length)"
        // Ex: android.packagingOptions.pickFirsts += '**/SCCS/**'
        options.each {
            android.packagingOptions[prop] += it
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    def isGifEnabled = (findProperty('expo.gif.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.enabled') ?: "") == "true";
    def isWebpAnimatedEnabled = (findProperty('expo.webp.animated') ?: "") == "true";

    if (isGifEnabled) {
        // For animated gif support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:${reactAndroidLibs.versions.fresco.get()}")
    }

    if (isWebpEnabled) {
        // For webp support
        implementation("com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:${reactAndroidLibs.versions.fresco.get()}")
        if (isWebpAnimatedEnabled) {
            // Animated webp support
            implementation("com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:${reactAndroidLibs.versions.fresco.get()}")
        }
    }

    implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-integration")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

expo-camera node_modules level:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'host.exp.exponent'
version = '14.1.3'

def expoModulesCorePlugin = new File(project(":expo-modules-core").projectDir.absolutePath, "ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle")
if (expoModulesCorePlugin.exists()) {
  apply from: expoModulesCorePlugin
  applyKotlinExpoModulesCorePlugin()
  // Remove this check, but keep the contents after SDK49 support is dropped
  if (safeExtGet("expoProvidesDefaultConfig", false)) {
    useExpoPublishing()
    useCoreDependencies()
  }
}

buildscript {
  // Simple helper that allows the root project to override versions declared by this library.
  ext.safeExtGet = { prop, fallback ->
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
  }

  // Ensures backward compatibility
  ext.getKotlinVersion = {
    if (ext.has("kotlinVersion")) {
      ext.kotlinVersion()
    } else {
      ext.safeExtGet("kotlinVersion", "1.8.10")
    }
  }

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${getKotlinVersion()}")
  }
}

// Remove this if and it's contents, when support for SDK49 is dropped
if (!safeExtGet("expoProvidesDefaultConfig", false)) {
  afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
      publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
          from components.release
        }
      }
      repositories {
        maven {
          url = mavenLocal().url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

android {
  // Remove this if and it's contents, when support for SDK49 is dropped
  if (!safeExtGet("expoProvidesDefaultConfig", false)) {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet("compileSdkVersion", 34)

    defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion safeExtGet("minSdkVersion", 23)
      targetSdkVersion safeExtGet("targetSdkVersion", 34)
    }

    publishing {
      singleVariant("release") {
        withSourcesJar()
      }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
    }
  }

  def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
  if (agpVersion.tokenize('.')[0].toInteger() < 8) {
    compileOptions {
      sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
      targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.majorVersion
    }
  }

  namespace "expo.modules.camera"
  defaultConfig {
    versionCode 32
    versionName "14.1.3"
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    url "$projectDir/maven"
  }
}

dependencies {
  // Remove this if and it's contents, when support for SDK49 is dropped
  if (!safeExtGet("expoProvidesDefaultConfig", false)) {
    implementation project(':expo-modules-core')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${getKotlinVersion()}"
  }
  def camerax_version = "1.4.0-alpha02"

  api "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6"
  api 'com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0'

  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:${camerax_version}"
  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:${camerax_version}"

  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:${camerax_version}"
  implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:${camerax_version}"
  implementation "com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0"
  implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.4.0-alpha02'

  api 'com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0'
}

My app.json:
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "*********",
        "slug": "*********",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash_screen.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": [
            "**/*"
        ],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true,
            "bundleIdentifier": "**.**.*****.***********",
            "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
        },
        "android": {
            "splash": {
                "mdpi": "./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/splashscreen_image.webp",
                "hdpi": "./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/splashscreen_image.webp",
                "xhdpi": "./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/splashscreen_image.webp",
                "xxhdpi": "./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/splashscreen_image.webp",
                "xxxhdpi": "./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/splashscreen_image.webp"
            },
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            },
            "package": "**.**.*****.***********",
            "permissions": [
                "android.permission.BLUETOOTH",
                "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN",
                "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"
            ],
            "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
        },
        "extra": {
            "eas": {
                "projectId": "********-****-****-****-************"
            }
        },
        "plugins": [
            [
                "expo-camera",
                {
                    "cameraPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera to create a profile picture?"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}


Are you using an Expo managed workflow? If possible can you sure your app.json file?

@samcodee It's an Expo managed workflow. I've added my app.json. I've deliberately blanked out the name, slug & bundle identifier.

Hey there! I have used expo-camera in a previous project long back. I remember facing a similar error. I suggest you 1) Reinstall the ExpoCamera package. 2) Try deleting the android and ios folders and regenerate it (It is recommended configuration is done from app.json instead of modifying those folders directly.) (Backup those folders first!) 3) Try adding  "android.permission.CAMERA", in the android permissions.
I am not that knowledgable in RN, so I apologize in advance!

@samcodee I downgraded the expo-camera version and it seems to have solved the problem! However, the same problem exists for expo-dev-client and downgrading that isn't solving it.

In my project, i used these versions:     "expo-camera": "~15.0.15",
"expo-dev-client": "~4.0.26",
I also suggest upgrading expo packages so that u ensure all of them are compatible with each other.
